# Is this an intramolecular SN2 reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

What's the mechanism of the following reaction? Seems like internal attack occurs, but would be great if someone could provide a step by step mechanism.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, mechanism of this reaction involves internal attack.

[image]